# Scraping from a javascript website requiring login using R/Rvest

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to use R/R Studio to scrape information from a website that both requires a login and uses javascript. As it stands, my code currently yields the output: 'NA' or 'NA_character' for scraped information, which is not correct (should be a number or character text).

I have successfully scraped from non-login websites in the past but fear this one is more advanced on many levels. I have read that if a website uses javascript, this changes the scraping process. I am feeling overwhelmed by the options at my disposal however, and wanted to consult StackOverflow experts. This resource (https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#rvest7.3) recommends three options:

1. execute javascript in R 2) use developer tools 3) use RSelenium

I have played around with options 1 and 2. Option 1 seems like it relies on receiving a javascript output from the scraping process, which is not being provided by the 'NA' 'NA_character' outputs from my scraping. I have experimented with Option 2 (new to dev tools) and found what my gut tells me is insufficient (does not match well to tutorial, lacks a lot of the sought-after keywords).

I am curious to see how this community would go about handling this problem and scraping from this specific website. Any insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated -- have spent a ton of time on this and decided it was time to reach out to others. Thank you for your time.

```
#scrape link
link_of_interest <- "https://www.cdp.net/en/formatted_responses/responses?campaign_id=70692136&discloser_id=857156&locale=en&organization_name=Goldman+Sachs+Group+Inc.&organization_number=7599&program=Investor&project_year=2020&redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fcdp.credit360.com%2Fsurveys%2F6sc15v4h%2F92645&survey_id=68887525"

#login
login <- "https://www.cdp.net/en/users/sign_in"
pgsession<- html_session(login)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)
login_form <- pgform[[1]]
login_form
filled_form <- set_values(login_form, "user[email]" = "*******", "user[password]" = "******")
filled_form
logged_in_session <- submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
scrape_session <- logged_in_session %>% 
  (jump_to(pgsession, link_of_interest))

#scrape: 
scrape_tag <- '.ndp_formatted_response__header+ .ndp_formatted_response__question .ndp_formatted_response__value'  #example tag
scraped_information <- scrape_session %>% html_node(scrape_tag) %>% html_text()
```

Other notes: I am unsure what the brackets and number in:" pgform[[1]]" actually do but I believe I am using them properly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the easiest way is, if you succeed tu open it, is to use RSelenium and the following function:

First you have to find the element where to put your login and password

````
```
Login <- remDr$findElement('css selector', 'CSS-login')
Password <- remDr$findElement('css selector', 'CSS-password')
# You can also, of course, use XPath
```
````

Then you use the following to enter your informations

````
```
Login$sendKeysToElement(list("YourLogin"))
Password$sendKeysToElement(list("YourPassword"))
```
````

Then you have to fin where is the login button and click it

````
```
frames <- remDr$findElements("css selector", 'CCS-LoginInButton')

frames[[1]]$clickElement()
```
````

Then you should be connected.